# Does anyone know what these characters means?

Tags: characters, character-identification, traditional-characters, seal

My name is Javier.[image]

Im writting because i don t understand what a seal inscription would be traslated.
if anyone could hel`me i woul appreciate very much.
Regards.

Comment: Top right looks like 定, top left like 廟. No idea about the other two. Also, this is based on the original view - I can't make any of them intelligible on the flipped view (which is weird if it's on a seal, which should be flipped).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned and likely won't benefit future readers